# ImageResizer disposing provided Image reference

Tags: .net, image-processing, imageresizer

We are using the image resizer from imageresizing.net and are seeing some weird behaviour.

When we read an image in from a stream and then resize the image we can no longer access the properties of the original image.

The following code will reproduce the issue.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(var httpPostedFileBaseImage = new FileStream(@"C:\test.jpg",FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                using(var uploadedImage = Image.FromStream(httpPostedFileBaseImage))
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(uploadedImage.Width);
                    var resizedImage = ImageBuilder.Current.Build(uploadedImage,
                                                                  new ResizeSettings("width=110;height=83"));

                    Console.WriteLine(uploadedImage.Width);
                }
            }
        }
```

Before the ImageBuilder line we are able to see the uploadedImage.Width fine but afterwards it throws an exception:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
       at ConsoleApplication6.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\ConsoleApplication6\ConsoleApplication6\Program.cs:line 25
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Is there something that we are doing wrong here or could this possibly be a bug in the image resizer?

Note: the problem was originally from an asp.net mvc app that has images uploaded which is why the variable is called httpPostedFileBaseImage and we are using Image.FromStream instead of perhaps Image.FromFile

The image is [image] but it appears to happen on most images.

EDIT:

Tried the following after the image resizing to no avail

```
httpPostedFileBaseImage.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

EDIT2:

This is what confused me
[image]

The documentation seems to suggest that "it will not be disposed unless disposeSource=true, or am I misreading this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't know how I missed it but there is an parameter to the ImageBuilder that tells it not to dispose the source

```
var resizedImage = ImageBuilder.Current.Build(uploadedImage,new ResizeSettings("width=110;height=83"),false);
```

Even though this fixes it, its strange as the documentation says its false by default

Comment: Didn't I tell you this in your original e-mail?

Comment: The xml doc says "If passed a source Stream, Bitmap, or Image instance, it will be disposed after use. Use disposeSource=False to disable that behavior."

Comment: I'm not sure what is confusing.

Comment: Ah, you're looking at the docs for a different overload. It makes more sense stated the opposite way, I'll change that.

Comment: I'm getting the same error message, even the related stack trace is also same. I'm using lazy initialization. I'm viewing the image in a picturebox, so far so good. But when I try to view draw this image in a panel, I'm getting this error message. Is there any chance it's related to `Lazy`?

Comment: Hey, thanks, I've found the problem. The same problem you are having. I was disposing the image.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try resetting the stream position to 0 ? If your image resizing library moves it forward, you need to rewind it before using it again.